# Is there a way to override a property in an interface when the interface is inherited?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**Environment:**
MVC4
C#
VS2010

**Problem:**
I have an interface that I am considering my "Base" Interface that is defined as follows:

```
public interface ITestModel
{
    TestViewModel model { get; set; }

    void PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(Int32 ReferralTypeID, Int32 profileid, string UniqueKeyValues);
    void Save();
}

[MetadataType(typeof(MetaData_TestViewModel))]
public partial class TestViewModel
{
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData_TestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required")]
    [DisplayName("Primary Key")]
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("New Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Comments")]
    public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

**Using the interface:**

If I do the following everything works as I want:

```
public class BaseViewModel : ITestModel
{
    private TestViewModel _model;
    public TestViewModel model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; }
    }

    public void PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(Int32 ReferralTypeID, Int32 profileid, string UniqueKeyValues)
    {
        model = new TestViewModel();
        model.id = ReferralTypeID;
        model.name = "TEst";
        model.comments = "This is a comment";
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        int i = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

Now I want to inherit the "Base" Interface but change the definition of model property with a definition that is inherited from the TestViewModel as follows:

```
public interface ITestModelB : ITestModel
{
    new TestViewModelB model { get; set; }

}

public class TestViewModelB : TestViewModel
{
    public int anotherfield { get; set; }
    public string anotherstringfield { get; set; }
}
```

And use the interface as follows:

```
public class AViewModel : ITestModelB
{

    private TestViewModelB _model;
    public TestViewModelB model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            _model = value;
        }
    }

    public void PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(Int32 ReferralTypeID, Int32 profileid, string UniqueKeyValues)
    {
        model = new TestViewModelB();
        model.comments = "New model created";
        model.id = 1;
        model.name = "Referral Type 1";
        model.anotherfield = profileid;
        model.anotherstringfield = UniqueKeyValues;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        int i = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I build I get the following error:

```
Error   1   'InterfaceTest.Models.AViewModel' does not implement interface member 'InterfaceTest.Models.ITestModel.model'. 'InterfaceTest.Models.AViewModel.model' cannot implement 'InterfaceTest.Models.ITestModel.model' because it does not have the matching return type of 'InterfaceTest.Models.TestViewModel'.
```

**Why I want to do this:**

I have a referral system that I am trying to build where all referrals have the same base properties and actions.  Each referral type also has properties and actions specific to the referral type.  I want the referrals to flow through the same controllers so that when a new referral is added, I only have to create a new interface to handle the referral.

Here is what I want to be able to do in my controllers:

```
ITestModel model = businessLogic.GetModel(referraltypeid);
model.PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(1, 1234, "DRC Policy, 12345678, 2/14/2014");
```

I would use a method in my businessLogic class to determine which model type to return based on the referral type.  All models would implement the ITestModel interface.  Doing this would allow me to handle all referrals through the same controller rather than having to have multiple controllers for each referral type.

**What I need**
Can anyone tell me how to overcome the error I'm getting when I build or suggest another solution for what I want to accomplish?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi dyarosh! Maybe you should be using Generics in your interface, with a TModel or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of an compile error using explicit interface implementation

```
    public class AViewModel : ITestModelB
    {

        private TestViewModelB _model;
        public TestViewModelB model
        {
            get
            {
                return _model;
            }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
            }
        }

        private TestViewModel newmodel;
        TestViewModel ITestModel.model
        {
            get { return newmodel; }
            set { newmodel = value; }
        }

        public void PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(Int32 ReferralTypeID, Int32 profileid, string UniqueKeyValues)
        {
            model = new TestViewModelB();
            model.comments = "New model created";
            model.id = 1;
            model.name = "Referral Type 1";
            model.anotherfield = profileid;
            model.anotherstringfield = UniqueKeyValues;
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            int i = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Or maybe use generic interface

```
public interface ITestModel<Tmodel>
{
    Tmodel model { get; set; }

    void PopulateNewReferralRequestModel(Int32 ReferralTypeID, Int32 profileid, string UniqueKeyValues);
    void Save();
}
```